# Designing Kinect Application Interface in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, interface, kinect

My friends and I would like to make a home management system targeting Windows and utilizing Kinect.  Is it possible to use silverlight with kinect?  We are thinking of an interface that mimics xbox's where a user can reach to different parts of the screen and manage their home.

Answer (score 1):

I'm coding with Kinect and I can say you that work fine in silverlight. You have just to make a wpf project and download the sdk 1.0 for kinect. You can find a lot of example on the Internet. 
For example: http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect
Furthermore I've just made a system to manage the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it should work fine. The SDK supports C# & WPF so.

I googled it quick and found [this](http://silverlightkinect.codeplex.com/) which are SL & Kinect Interop demos